# Is it possible to change the top color of safari for iPhone with ReactJS?

Tags: css, reactjs, iphone, responsive-design, frontend

I'm trying to change the upper part of my application made with ReactJs, which can be modified on Iphone X and later. I have seen that with react-native it is possible but I can't find a way to do it with react. If anyone can help me I appreciate it

Comment: The notch row background color? Is the application `reactjs` or `react-native`? Just confirming again.

Comment: the app is reactJS @AseemGautam

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Version 15, Safari supports the theme-color `<meta>` tag both on macOS and iOS.

Add this to `index.html`

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#319197">
```

In depth, [here](https://css-tricks.com/meta-theme-color-and-trickery/).